# Another MySQL daemon is already running?

Tags: apache2, mysql, services, xampp

```
root@jose-desktop:~# sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
Starting XAMPP for Linux 1.7.7...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...
XAMPP: Another MySQL daemon is already running.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...
XAMPP for Linux started.
```

I managed to connect the Apache but, now,,, Another MySql daemon is already running? still appearing and I can't connect MySQL

any help?

Answer (score 3):

Have you got the ubuntu mysql installed as well as the LAMPP one? I would stop everything and then stat LAMPP

```
 sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop
 sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
 sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply run this command to terminal

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```

and after that

```
/opt/lampp/lampp/ start
```

trust me this actually works on me!! 100%

Answer (score 0):

Try Below command it should stop the mysql service at your end :

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

Let me know if it doesn't, I can brief ahead if you have difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

Find the mysql pid and kill all those child processes. You should be able to kill those child pids as follows

pkill -TERM -P `pid of mysql`

Then check if you are able to start lamp!

Answer (score 0):

mysql is already running 
open your terminal with ctrl+alt+T and type the following command...

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld stop
```

if not working this command then please type...

```
sudo /opt/lampp/sbin/mysqld stop
```